# I would like to analyze the image with tensorflw.js - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js

**mobilenet.js**

```
var loadFrozenModel = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-converter');
var NamedTensorMap = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-converter');
var tfc = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-core');
var IMAGENET_CLASSES = require('./imagenet_classes');


const GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_DIR =     'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/';
const MODEL_FILE_URL = 'mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/optimized_model.pb';
const WEIGHT_MANIFEST_FILE_URL = 'mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/weights_manifest.json';
const INPUT_NODE_NAME = 'input';
const OUTPUT_NODE_NAME = 'MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1';
const PREPROCESS_DIVISOR = tfc.scalar(255 / 2);

class MobileNet {
  constructor() {}

  async load() {
    this.model = await loadFrozenModel(
        GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_DIR + MODEL_FILE_URL,
        GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_DIR + WEIGHT_MANIFEST_FILE_URL);
}

  dispose() {
    if (this.model) {
      this.model.dispose();
    }
  }

  predict(input) {
    const preprocessedInput = tfc.div(
        tfc.sub(input.asType('float32'), PREPROCESS_DIVISOR),
         PREPROCESS_DIVISOR);
    const reshapedInput =
        preprocessedInput.reshape([1, ...preprocessedInput.shape]);
    const dict = {};
    dict[INPUT_NODE_NAME] = reshapedInput;
    return this.model.execute(dict, OUTPUT_NODE_NAME);
  }

  getTopKClasses(predictions, topK) {
    const values = predictions.dataSync();
    predictions.dispose();

    let predictionList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      predictionList.push({value: values[i], index: i});
    }
    predictionList = predictionList
                         .sort((a, b) => {
                           return b.value - a.value;
                         })
                         .slice(0, topK);
    return predictionList.map(x => {
      return {label: IMAGENET_CLASSES[x.index], value: x.value};
    });
  }
}

module.exports = MobileNet;
```

**test.js**

```
  var tfc = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-core');
  var MobileNet = require('./mobilenet');
  var fs = require('fs');
  var image = require('get-image-data')

  var i = 0;

  var meta;

  image('./cat.jpg', function(err, getImageData){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('start to image data ');

    console.log(i++);

    console.log("meta : " + getImageData.data.length);
    console.log("getImageData :"+getImageData);

    const mobileNet = new MobileNet();
    console.time('Loading of model');

    // await mobileNet.load();
    console.timeEnd('Loading of model');
    console.log("maybee this is error on the data type");

    const pixels = tfc.fromPixels(image);

    console.time('First prediction');
    let result = mobileNet.predict(pixels);
    const topK = mobileNet.getTopKClasses(result, 5);
    console.timeEnd('First prediction');

    resultElement.innerText = '';
    topK.forEach(x => {
      resultElement.innerText += `${x.value.toFixed(3)}: ${x.label}\n`;
    });

    console.time('Subsequent predictions');
    result = mobileNet.predict(pixels);
    mobileNet.getTopKClasses(result, 5);
    console.timeEnd('Subsequent predictions');

    mobileNet.dispose();
  });
```

I want to analyze the image using the tensorflow.js.
But it doesn't work.

ReferenceError: ImageData is not defined
    at MathBackendCPU.fromPixels (/Users/leeyongmin/Documents/tfjs-converter-master-2/demo/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/kernels/backend_cpu.js:75:31)
    at Engine.fromPixels (/Users/leeyongmin/Documents/tfjs-converter-master-2/demo/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:292:29)
    at ArrayOps.fromPixels (/Users/leeyongmin/Documents/tfjs-converter-master-2/demo/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/array_ops.js:195:41)
    at /Users/leeyongmin/Documents/tfjs-converter-master-2/demo/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/operation.js:11:61
    at Object.Tracking.tidy (/Users/leeyongmin/Documents/tfjs-converter-master-2/demo/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tracking.js:36:22)
    at Object.descriptor.value [as fromPixels] (/Users/leeyongmin/Documents/tfjs-converter-master-2/demo/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/operation.js:11:26)
    at /Users/leeyongmin/Documents/tfjs-converter-master-2/demo/test.js:26:22
    at /Users/leeyongmin/Documents/tfjs-converter-master-2/demo/node_modules/get-image-data/index.js:18:7
    at load (/Users/leeyongmin/Documents/tfjs-converter-master-2/demo/node_modules/get-image/server.js:18:5)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)